# How to fill dynamic handlebars with context in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In our database we use dynamic handlebars.  We already have a function compiling the handlebars from the database, but without injecting context (see code below).

But how to write a function to add context to the handlebars?

We have a model `content element`

```
var ContentElement = DS.Model.extend({
  key: DS.attr('string'),
  value: DS.attr('string'),
  template: function(){
    return Ember.Handlebars.compile(this.get('value'));
  }.property('value'),
  handlebarsHtml: function() {
    return Ember.View.create({
      template: this.get('template')
    });
  }.property('template'),
});
export default ContentElement;
```

In the route we set the content element as the `landing` variable

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.store.find('contentElement', { project_id: model.get('id'), key: 'signup.landing'     }).then(function(contentElements) {
    controller.set('landing', contentElements.get('firstObject'));
  });
  return this._super(controller, model);
}
```

In the handlebars

```
{{view Ember.ContainerView currentViewBinding='landing.handlebarsHtml'}}
```

An example what you can expect from the database:

```
Tell your friend about {{product.name}}!
```

Where `product.name` has to be filled by Ember.

---

We use ember-cli `0.0.24`, ember `1.5.1` and ember data `1.0.0.beta8`

Answer (score 0):

This code already works! And we use it now with a custom helper. So the model will stay clean and the handlebars will be beautiful.

[Use custom helpers in Handlebars which are loaded from an api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955389/use-custom-helpers-in-handlebars-which-are-loaded-from-an-api)